# out of memory error java while sending continous web cam images

Tags: java, serversocket, objectinputstream

I was trying to send continuous images from webcam (Using Webcam-api)from a client via an ObjectOutStream to server and show it on a label of a frame and found a code on youtube but the program throws out of memory error after some time. Can anyone Explain its reason? May be the inputStream on server side is Storing all the images which is not required. If so Suggest any methods to clear InputStream on server.

TestClient :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;

public class TestClient {


    static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
        System.out.println(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
        webcam.open();

        socket = new Socket("localhost",5001);
        
        ObjectOutputStream dout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client");

        frame.setSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        label.setSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
        label.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        while(true) {
            BufferedImage wc = webcam.getImage();
            ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(wc);
            label.setIcon(ic);
            dout.writeObject(ic);
            dout.flush();
        }

    }
}
```

TestServer:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5001);
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected ..");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ServerSide");
        
        frame.setSize(640,480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        label.setSize(640,480);
        label.setVisible(true);
        
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        while(true) {
            label.setIcon((ImageIcon)in.readObject());
        }
            
    }
    

}
```

Error after sometime::

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:78)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2036)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.readObject(ImageIcon.java:501)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1175)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2295)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2166)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
    at TestServer.main(TestServer.java:29)
```

EDIT::
I tried this but server is recieving image for only first time after that it raises null point exception. I am not able figure out why ?

Client:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while(true) {
   BufferedImage wc = webcam.getImage();
   ImageIO.write(wc, "jpg", bos); 
   byte imgBytes[] = bos.toByteArray();
   out.write(imgBytes,0,imgBytes.length);
   bos.flush();
}
```

Server ::

```
DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
ImageInputStream imgin = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);

while(true){
    BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(imgin);
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(img);
    label.setIcon(ic);
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `Thread.sleep` in any of the loops (either on client or on server) and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Neither InputStream nor ObjectInputStream can be 'cleared' and they do not 'store' any previous results. Most likely the bits on the wire are corrupted, and the data being sent is causing the read operation to try to allocate a gigantic array 'by accident'.

Note that sending ImageIcons over an ObjectOutputStream is incredibly inefficient; the protocol wastes tons of bandwidth, and wastes plenty of CPU cycles trying to serialize that object, which wasn't designed for this. Better to save your image into some fast image format (probably not PNG, though), and send that, which in passing also would make it far easier to debug corrupted sends.

Comment: That cannot be true: `Most likely the bits on the wire are corrupted, and the data being sent is causing the read operation to try to allocate a gigantic array 'by accident'.` How can the bits on the wire be corrupted? If it were like that the Internet would never work. There are specific checks in place starting with java serialization / deserialization and ending with TCP protocol and so on. Almost all layers have some checks in place to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Version issues between classes (serialVersionUID then overriding the check on this), for example.

Comment: But version issues result in runtime exceptions they don't result in out of memory errors do they?

Comment: They do. As in, if there are different versions of the object but sVUID is set (a common practice), field misalignment occurs.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing here is continuously setting the label's icon:

```
while(true) {
            label.setIcon((ImageIcon)in.readObject());
        }
```

What this code does it will create new instances of `ImageIcon`, link `label` to that instance and then, when a new image comes in, the reference to the original object is lost and garbage collector cannot clear it or doesn't get a chance to clear it as this is happening in a loop without any pauses.

So if the camera generates continuously 60 frames per second, the garbage collector will not have the chance to clear memory as (hypothetically) 60 objects per second will be created in memory.

You can monitor your app using jvisualvm and see that is the case.

Comment: None of this is true. in.readObject() ends up freezing this thread (as, eventually, you get to the network socket, which blocks), at which point the garbage collector will kick in just peachy fine. Even if a thread never blocks, it will GC just fine; once you ask the VM for an allocation that it cannot give you, it'll (usually, it's complicated) GC first.

Comment: I am not saying it is 100% true, but that is my theory. It will not halt at the socket if there are objects available to be read.

Comment: Your theory is based on misconceptions about how the VM works. It cannot be true.

Comment: I tried adding system.gc(); in each loop it still crashed .

Comment: .. that's because this answer makes no sense, @AAYUSHSHANDILYA

Comment: @AAYUSHSHANDILYA I asked you to try to put a sleep in the while loop, not to call gc: `Try adding a Thread.sleep in any of the loops (either on client or on server) and see what happens`

Comment: That wouldn't change anything whatsoever.

Comment: I tried by Thread.sleep(50) after which program ran a little longer but crashed afterwards...

Comment: Could be that swing is using that object that you set `jlabel.setIcon` and tries to display it and keeps references to that object causing GC not to be able to collect them